# Align ListView with other View

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have an `EditText`, which gets aligned with other `TextView` below it.

[image]

But as soon as I add `ListView`, and try to Left align with plain text at the top the width and location of the `EditText` and `TextView` fields below it changes.

Also, if I try to use another Linear Layout instead of a `ListView` I face the same issue. What wrong could I be doing here?

I have tried setting width and height of listView, to match_contraint, but that did not work too.

[image]

Below is the xml for it,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.testapp.app">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/listView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView4"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="472dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="123dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want? Your Question isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you put constraints in the wrong direction. So you aligned all `TextView`s to the start of the `EditText`. But `EditText` in its turn is aligned to the start of the `ListView`.

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/listView4"
```

And as ListView doesn't have aligning, it is positioned at (0, 0), I guess.